# Connect my lollipop device via USB in mass storage mode

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-s-5, mtp, usb-mass-storage

I have Samsung S5 dual sim variant which runs on android v5.0 stock based custom rom, and having some trouble with MTP mode such as very slow copying speed and can't play media directy (I have to copy each file to my local storage and then play them) is there any way I can connec it in mass storage mode so that it acts like a flash drive?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do it because your Android doesn't has any support for it. There may be some massive hack which I don't know but I would rather prefer a file / local http server on my phone to get the things done, streaming too (see [Is there a viable alternative to MTP for file transfer?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/91900/96277)), or perhaps use the method [Izzy once mentioned here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/89525/96277)

Comment: @brauliobo, it is not possible to have that actual USB mass storage functionality since Android natively doesn't support it in Lollipop or Kitkat. However, there are various ways to achieve what you want ranging from accessing filesystem using ADB to mounting a server running on Android in PC. I just want to know the exact requirement of yours and the clarification: *did you consider any of the solutions mentioned in my earlier comment*?

Comment: yeah, I've ended up using an ssh daemon and transfered data via scp command, but the ideal for me would be an rsync daemon, but couldn't find a good app with it.

Comment: @brauliobo some busybox variants might have that built-in. I only know apps for the opposite direction (working from the Android device), see [Synchronisation via SSH](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_sync#group_169)

Comment: Related: [Why can't I see Android storage as a partition on PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205559/218526)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connecting your phone via UMS (USB Mass Storage) won't be possible. It's been removed from Android, so the only way would be for you to fork the Android source and program it in again. I assume that's not what you want to do.
There were a few reasons for this, but mostly because UMS is prone to crash third-party apps and also files cannot be dual accessed from apps and the computer simultaneously. 
MTP isn't really bad per-se, but unfortunately the support in Windows is lacking. A colleague of mine uses MTP with Ubuntu and is very happy with it.

Here are some suggestions about what you could do though:

- If you really want to transfer files via USB, you could do that with `adb pull` and `adb push`. You could make a little script that runs as soon as you connect your phone and synchronizes a specific folder.
- You could, and this is the most comfortable way, install a samba server on your phone. That way you would be able to mount parts of your phone's storage on your computer, as soon as it is connected to your WiFi. The bandwidth would probably also be enough to directly play music files, maybe even videos (depending mostly on the number of antennas your phone has). For that solution, please have a look at these two apps [SambaDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=berserker.android.apps.sambadroid&hl=en), [Samba Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.sambaserver&hl=en) as well as this question regarding root access [Using SMB server without root access](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1705/using-smb-server-without-root-access).
- Another option would be running an [SSH server](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=ssh%20server&c=apps&hl=en). You can then also mount remotely with SSHFS on Linux and OSX. For Windows I recommend [SFTP Net Drive](https://www.eldos.com/sftp-net-drive/download-prerelease.php#product), which is free for a single connection and personal use. Advantages over SMB would be that file transfers are encrypted and that it's more suitable to also be used over WAN. Also it already comes with file integrity checks. Disadvantages would be that over high latency connections (WAN), speeds might drop significantly due to physical limitations from the bandwidth delay product.
- Last but not least, there is the option, if you're on Linux, to use [adbfs](https://github.com/spion/adbfs-rootless). It is using FUSE to mount your adb connected phone. So it will appear just like any other mount. This is probably the closest you can get to what was UMS.

Answer (score 1):

You can install app to enable USB mass storage. Download apk from [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/app-universal-mass-storage-enabler-beta-t3240097) and just select the '**Enable UMS (Hard Method)**' in that app..

Source;
[Enable MASS STORAGE Mode](http://forum.xda-developers.com/crossdevice-dev/android-one-general/tweak-enable-mass-storage-usb-mode-t3128839)

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the relevant parts from that XDA thread, so future readers can see the solution.

Answer (score -1):

On my lollipop system ( custom rom) it wasn't option to change usb connectivity, but actually it was, all I need to do do is to plug phone to pc via usb, then go to settings and in search box (it must have coz it is lp), and type there usb, you'll get  something like usb connection, tap on it an you'll get standard menu to chosse between MTP, PTP, charge only, an usb mass storage.

Comment: Which custom ROM and which build of it exactly? USB mass storage (UMS) on Lollipop? That's interesting. Is it ROM available for Samsung S5 dual SIM variant or the device which brauliobo is yet to mention?

Comment: On my stock-based custom rom(xstrestolite) for Samsung galaxy S5, I've tried this but there is no option related to UMS.

Comment: Sorry i've forgot to say that I don't use samsung S5, I tought that this might work on your device, but it seems i'm wrong.. Maybe, but just maybe, you can try slimlp rom for your device if it exist, maybe there will be option with metod i've mentioned..

Comment: I've SlimLP (Android 5.1.1) for OnePlus One. I followed your method and I don't see UMS.