# Convert Android File Transfer to USB Removable Device in Lollipop

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, usb, file-transfer, usb-debugging, asus-zenfone-2

I have a [ASUS Zenfone2 Laser 500KL](https://www.asus.com/in/Phone/ZenFone-2-Laser-ZE500KL/) whose configuration are 8Gb Internal, 2gb RAM, QuadCore Processor and Android Lollipop 5.0. For some days, i am using the phone but i don't like the file transfer system from phone to PC by USB. **Some folders doesn't appear when i open it on Windows** but appears on phone when i access. It also appear when i connect SD card by Card Reader to the PC B but not by this file system.

When i connect the phone to PC in MyComputer this appears.

[image: My Computer]

Here to my question, i want to convert Portable Media Player to USB Mass Storage Removable Device by disabling this PC Suite and showing Portable Device. Can anyone help me how to do so?

Comment: Another Similar Question: ***[How to connect my Lollipop device via USB in Mass Storage Mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/114491/connect-my-lollipop-device-via-usb-in-mass-storage-mode)***

Comment: @GokulNC Well, as it is mentioned in that answer that it wouldn't be possible practically if your device doesn't support USB Mass Storage but why some of the folders not appearing on Windows that are visible on my Android phone..The missing folders only show when i connect the Sd card from a card reader?

Comment: Afraid there's no possibility that way. But there might be alternatives, see e.g. my list [Manage your Android Device from your Computer](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/various_remotemanagement).

Comment: Folder not appearing issue can be solved easily. I, Izzy and one other user have relevant answers on [Is there a viable alternative to MTP for file transfer?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/91900)